# htaccess two parameter mod-rewrite problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to setup a more friendly URL system and failing miserably. I want to be able to pass 1 or 2 GET parameters like this:

```
http://website.com/1234/123456
```

where `1234` is the first param and `123456` is the second param.

In my attempts Apache keeps viewing the `/1234/` as a folder ***and*** a parameter. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?id=$1&pa=$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&pa=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(?:([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)/?)?)?$ /index.php?id=$1&pa=$2 [L]
```

It's a little strict and messy, so you could just try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(([^/]*)(/?(.*)))?$ /index.php?id=$2&pa=$4 [L]
```

That will take everything past the last so `host.com/123/1233/56` will rewrite to `host.com/index.php?id=123&pa=1233/56` while the first won't rewrite it, because of the `56`

Comment: I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong. I've been playing with it for an hour, but with both of your examples it still sees the first parameter as a folder and a parameter.

Comment: @prattw it might be because of `index.php?id=$1` you might want to add the `/` so that it pulls it from the document root of the site instead of trying to pull it from where it thinks you are located. Not sure if that is the problem, but try it.